# Display Certain Columns in Javas Abstract Table Model

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to use JRadioButtons to display a certain Columns in my Abstract Table.
So I have 2 Columns in my table "Videos that are hired"and "Videos not Hired" I only want to show 1 of the Columns if the "Show all Hires" radio button is clicked then if the user clicks the "Show all" JRadioButton it will show both of the Columns.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), an `AbstractTableModel` is a model whereby your data is stored and a `JTable` provides the view component for your model.

Therefore, since you are interested in changing the way the data is presented, you can adjust the view component (the `JTable`) as such:

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumn("Videos Not Hired");
table.removeColumn(column); // remove this column from the view
table.addColumn(column); // add this column to the view
```

Comment: You could also define a `TableColumnModel` which had "hide" and "show" column functionality...more work in the short term, long term gain, just saying - as an alternative approach ;)

Comment: so i should do it outside the table class and add it in my DataManager Class where i add everything to the frame?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you could create a `TableColumnModel` which provided functionality that allowed you to hide/show columns

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * A simple column model to provide
 * easy visibility functionality, allowing columns to be easily hidden and shown
 */
public class MutableTableColumnModel extends DefaultTableColumnModel {

    private List<TableColumn> allTableColumns;

    public MutableTableColumnModel() {

        allTableColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>(10);

    }

    /**
     * Sets the visibility of the specified TableColumn. The call is ignored if
     * the TableColumn is not found in this column model or its visibility status
     * did not change.
     * <p>
     * @param column
     * @param visible its new visibility status
     */
    public void setColumnVisible(TableColumn column, boolean visible) {
        if (!visible) {
            super.removeColumn(column);
        } else {
            // find the visible index of the column:
            // iterate through both collections of visible and all columns, counting
            // visible columns up to the one that's about to be shown again
            int noVisibleColumns = tableColumns.size();
            int noInvisibleColumns = allTableColumns.size();
            int visibleIndex = 0;

            for (int invisibleIndex = 0; invisibleIndex < noInvisibleColumns; ++invisibleIndex) {
                TableColumn visibleColumn = (visibleIndex < noVisibleColumns ? (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(visibleIndex) : null);
                TableColumn testColumn = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(invisibleIndex);

                if (testColumn == column) {
                    if (visibleColumn != column) {
                        super.addColumn(column);
                        super.moveColumn(tableColumns.size() - 1, visibleIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                } else if (testColumn == visibleColumn) {
                    ++visibleIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes all columns in this model visible
     */
    public void showAllColumns() {
        int noColumns = allTableColumns.size();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < noColumns; ++columnIndex) {
            TableColumn visibleColumn = (columnIndex < tableColumns.size() ? (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(columnIndex) : null);
            TableColumn invisibleColumn = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(columnIndex);

            if (visibleColumn != invisibleColumn) {
                super.addColumn(invisibleColumn);
                super.moveColumn(tableColumns.size() - 1, columnIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Maps the index of the column in the table model at
     * <code>modelColumnIndex</code> to the TableColumn object. There may me
     * multiple TableColumn objects showing the same model column, though this is
     * uncommon. This method will always return the first visible or else the
     * first invisible column with the specified index.
     *
     * @param modelColumnIndex index of column in table model
     * @return table column object or null if no such column in this column model
     */
    public TableColumn getColumnByModelIndex(int modelColumnIndex) {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < allTableColumns.size(); ++columnIndex) {
            TableColumn column = (TableColumn) allTableColumns.get(columnIndex);
            if (column.getModelIndex() == modelColumnIndex) {
                return column;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks wether the specified column is currently visible.
     *
     * @param aColumn column to check
     * @return visibility of specified column (false if there is no such column at
     * all. [It's not visible, right?])
     */
    public boolean isColumnVisible(TableColumn aColumn) {
        return (tableColumns.indexOf(aColumn) >= 0);
    }

    /**
     * Append <code>column</code> to the right of exisiting columns. Posts
     * <code>columnAdded</code> event.
     *
     * @param column The column to be added
     * @see #removeColumn
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if <code>column</code> is
     * <code>null</code>
     */
    public void addColumn(TableColumn column) {
        allTableColumns.add(column);
        super.addColumn(column);
    }

    /**
     * Removes <code>column</code> from this column model. Posts
     * <code>columnRemoved</code> event. Will do nothing if the column is not in
     * this model.
     *
     * @param column the column to be added
     * @see #addColumn
     */
    public void removeColumn(TableColumn column) {
        int allColumnsIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(column);
        if (allColumnsIndex != -1) {
            allTableColumns.remove(allColumnsIndex);
        }
        super.removeColumn(column);
    }

    /**
     * Moves the column from <code>oldIndex</code> to <code>newIndex</code>. Posts
     *  <code>columnMoved</code> event. Will not move any columns if
     * <code>oldIndex</code> equals <code>newIndex</code>.
     *
     * @param    oldIndex    index of column to be moved
     * @param    newIndex    new index of the column
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException    if either <code>oldIndex</code> or
     * <code>newIndex</code> are not in [0, getColumnCount() - 1]
     */
    public void moveColumn(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        if ((oldIndex < 0) || (oldIndex >= getColumnCount())
                || (newIndex < 0) || (newIndex >= getColumnCount())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("moveColumn() - Index out of range");
        }

        TableColumn fromColumn = (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(oldIndex);
        TableColumn toColumn = (TableColumn) tableColumns.get(newIndex);

        int allColumnsOldIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(fromColumn);
        int allColumnsNewIndex = allTableColumns.indexOf(toColumn);

        if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
            allTableColumns.remove(allColumnsOldIndex);
            allTableColumns.add(allColumnsNewIndex, fromColumn);
        }

        super.moveColumn(oldIndex, newIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of columns in this model.
     *
     * @param onlyVisible if set only visible columns will be counted
     * @return    the number of columns in the <code>tableColumns</code> array
     * @see    #getColumns
     */
    public int getColumnCount(boolean onlyVisible) {
        List<TableColumn> columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        return columns.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an <code>Enumeration</code> of all the columns in the model.
     *
     * @param onlyVisible if set all invisible columns will be missing from the
     * enumeration.
     * @return an <code>Enumeration</code> of the columns in the model
     */
    public Iterator<TableColumn> getColumns(boolean onlyVisible) {

        List<TableColumn> columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(columns).iterator();

    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the first column whose identifier equals
     * <code>identifier</code>. Position is the the index in all visible columns
     * if <code>onlyVisible</code> is true or else the index in all columns.
     *
     * @param    identifier the identifier object to search for
     * @param    onlyVisible if set searches only visible columns
     *
     * @return    the index of the first column whose identifier equals
     * <code>identifier</code>
     *
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if <code>identifier</code> is
     * <code>null</code>, or if no <code>TableColumn</code> has this
     * <code>identifier</code>
     * @see    #getColumn
     */
    public int getColumnIndex(Object identifier, boolean onlyVisible) {
        if (identifier == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Identifier is null");
        }

        List<TableColumn> columns = (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns);
        int noColumns = columns.size();
        TableColumn column;

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < noColumns; ++columnIndex) {
            column = (TableColumn) columns.get(columnIndex);

            if (identifier.equals(column.getIdentifier())) {
                return columnIndex;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Identifier not found");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column at
     * <code>columnIndex</code>.
     *
     * @param    columnIndex    the index of the column desired
     * @param    onlyVisible    if set columnIndex is meant to be relative to all
     * visible columns only else it is the index in all columns
     *
     * @return    the <code>TableColumn</code> object for the column at
     * <code>columnIndex</code>
     */
    public TableColumn getColumn(int columnIndex, boolean onlyVisible) {

        return (onlyVisible ? tableColumns : allTableColumns).get(columnIndex);

    }

    /**
     * Returns all the columns
     *
     * @return
     */
    public TableColumn[] getAllColumns() {

        return allTableColumns.toArray(new TableColumn[allTableColumns.size()]);

    }

    public TableColumn[] getHiddenColumns() {

        List<TableColumn> lstColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>(10);

        for (TableColumn column : getAllColumns()) {

            if (!isColumnVisible(column)) {

                lstColumns.add(column);

            }

        }

        return lstColumns.toArray(new TableColumn[lstColumns.size()]);

    }

    public static MutableTableColumnModel createFromTableModel(TableModel model) {

        MutableTableColumnModel columnModel = new MutableTableColumnModel();
        if (model != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn newColumn = new TableColumn(i);
                columnModel.addColumn(newColumn);
            }
        }

        return columnModel;

    }

}
```

This could be applied to a `JTable` simply by using something like...

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
TableModel tm = ...;
table.setModel(tm);
table.setColumnModel(MutableTableColumnModel.createFromTableModel(tm));
```

You can then change the column visibility state using something like...

```
MutableColumnModel cm = (MutableColumnModel)table.getColumnnModel();
cm.setColumnVisible(column, false);
```

For example...

Comment: +1, but I'm thinking the `createFromTableModel(...)` method needs to set the header value of the TableColumn with the value from the TableModel: `newColumn.setHeaderValue( model.getColumnName(i) );`

Comment: @camickr Yeah, I thought that to, ripped the code directly from `JTable`'s `createDefaultColumnsFromModel` method just for this example ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a class to manage the visibility of the columns.

Check out the [Table Column Manager](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/). You can use the `TableColumnManager` on any `JTable` with a single line of code.

The `TableColumnManager` will also allow the user to hide/show `TableColumns` by right clicking on the table header.

Comment: +1 I like that.  I wonder if it would be better to create a "proxy" column model and apply it to the table or if that would be inferred as to much interference. The only other issue would if you had a few dozen columns :P (and yes, the place I work, a few dozen is a small set)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, `The only other issue would if you had a few dozen columns` - Didn't this about that. I guess I could always use Darryl's [Menu Scroller](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/menu-scroller/) to limit the size of the popup menu.

Comment: I'd probably wouldn't worry to much about it, but I had proposed we do what Windows Explorer do, so a limited number of "base/common" columns and then provide a "More..." option which shows a dialog with all of them, but that's our needs